# Xcode says that URL schemes are not in the correct format bc URL Schemes need to begin with alphabetical character but my 1st char is 'h' [http..]"

Tags: ios, angular, xcode, ionic-framework, app-store

When I try to distribute a built version of my Angular/Ionic app, I am given error `ERROR ITMS-90158` that my URL schemes must be in the correct format, and then goes on to explain how 'URL Schemes schemes need to begin with an alphabetical character.'

The URL Scheme the error cites begins with 'https://g'. 'h', of course, being an alphabetical character, leaves me a little confused. The other answers i checked for this answer all were using numbers or incorrect characters so their were not relevant to my situation.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?